# Objective-C issues with location services

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I am trying to make a simple app the will get the users longitude and latitude

I followed the tutorial here:

http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/

and came with this:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        _longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
@end
```

My issue is that "Would like to use your current location" popup.

and none of the delegate methods are being hit, at all. I put a break point at the beginning of each delegate method and nothing. Please help.

Comment: On which version of iOS are you debuging?

Comment: is location manager nil ?

Comment: iOS 9 and location manager is not nil

Comment: try deleting the app, and run it again in different simulators. See if you can reproduce this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure you have following keys in your `info.plist`:

1. `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` with value `I need Location`
2. `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` with value `I need Location`
3. `privacy - location usage description` with value `I need Location`

Comment: The added the following to my plist and still did not work

Comment: I didn't quite get it. Can you please briefly explain what fixed it as this might be useful tip for others.

Comment: Adding the items to my .plist and this `[locationmanager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
       //or (as per your app requirement)
       [locationmanager requestAlwaysAuthorization];` without the iOS 8 condition

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the info.plist details as answered earlier and then add the below code during your initialization;

```
 if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
       [locationmanager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
       //or (as per your app requirement)
       [locationmanager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
```

Comment: location manager requests authorisation regardless the iOS. Why do you check for the ios version ?

Comment: The methods are available only for iOS8 and above

Comment: Hope you know how to refer documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html

Comment: Show me the line that states anyone of that method avilable from ios 8 or onwards

Comment: why are you referring the tvOS ? @Sachin

Comment: Search for that function in the documentation and not the CLLocationManager. And then check for its Availability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90350/discussion-between-sachin-and-mr-t).